# Extract Consecutive Digits from a String using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I've written a sub that extracts all the digits from a string in cell A1 and pastes the result in cell A2. This loops through each row repeating the process until all cells containing strings have been worked through.

However, I would like to only extract the numbers that are consecutive (more than 1 digit)

for example: 
from this string: **string-pattern-7---62378250-stringpattern.html** I only want to extract the digits **62378250** and not the preceding **7**.

How should I alter my code to achieve this?

```
Option Explicit

Function onlyDigits(s As String) As String
    ' Variables needed (remember to use "option explicit").   '
    Dim retval As String    ' This is the return string.      '
    Dim i As Integer        ' Counter for character position. '

    ' Initialise return string to empty                       '
    retval = ""

    ' For every character in input string, copy digits to     '
    '   return string.                                        '
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        If Mid(s, i, 1) >= "0" And Mid(s, i, 1) <= "9" Then
            retval = retval + Mid(s, i, 1)
        End If
    Next

    ' Then return the return string.                          '
    onlyDigits = retval
End Function


Sub extractDigits()

Dim myStr As String

Do While ActiveCell.Value <> Empty
        myStr = onlyDigits(ActiveCell.Value)
        ActiveCell(1, 2).Value = myStr
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: split the string based on "" into an array, then iterate (loop) the array

Comment: Are the strings you are interested in always delimited by `"-"`, or can the surrounding characters be other nondigit symbols? Also -- what would you do if there exists more than one run of consecutive digits, or is that not a problem?

Comment: Thank you for your prompt responses and help. The strings always change, sometimes have more than one "-" or none. Usually there is only one run of consecutive digits.

Answer (score 5):

Think this should do it if you only have one sequence

```
Function onlyDigits(v As Variant) As String

With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    .Pattern = "\d{2,}"
    If .Test(v) Then onlyDigits = .Execute(v)(0)
End With

End Function
```

Comment: Nice. I was wondering if someone would give an re solution. +1

Comment: @JohnColeman - thank you John, am always slightly wary of messing up RE.

Comment: VBScript's implementation is on the clunky side. I use it sometimes but so infrequently that I usually have to spend time looking at the documentation to remind myself how it works. More often than not in VBA I can cobble together something using `Like` which does what I need and doesn't require all sorts of trial and error.

Comment: Agreed, often it's not necessary but I like to use it as it does make me have to think. Like you I usually have to resort to checking syntax and testing.

Comment: Nice. The OP may want to use `.Global` if there is more than 1 string to extract.

Comment: Thank you @brettdj - yes the code would need adjusting, but based on the OP's code I'm assuming there is only one match.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
Public Function onlyDigits(s As String) As String
    Dim L As Long, s2 As String, i As Long, Kapture As Boolean
    Dim CH As String, temp As String

    s2 = s & " "
    L = Len(s2)
    Kapture = False
    temp = ""
    onlyDigits = ""

    For i = 1 To L
        CH = Mid(s2, i, 1)
        If IsNumeric(CH) Then
            temp = temp & CH
            If Len(temp) > 1 Then Kapture = True
        Else
            If Len(temp) < 2 Then
                temp = ""
            Else
                If Kapture Then
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    If Kapture Then onlyDigits = temp
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant, thank you very much, this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly similar to the excellent answer of @Gary'sStudent but has a slightly different structure:

```
Function ConsecutiveDigits(s As String) As String
    'returns the first substring consisting of 2 or more
    'consecutive digits which is delimited by either a
    'nondigit or the edge of the string
    'returns empty string if no such subtring exists

    Dim i As Long
    Dim c As String
    Dim digits As String

    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        c = Mid(s, i, 1)
        If IsNumeric(c) Then
            digits = digits & c
        Else
            If Len(digits) > 1 Then
                ConsecutiveDigits = digits
                Exit Function
            Else
                digits = "" 'reset
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    'we are at the end of the string -- should we return digits?
    If Len(digits) > 1 Then ConsecutiveDigits = digits
    'else return default empty string

End Function
```